# Flutter: "Expected an Identifier" and "Expected to find ')'" when inserting "if" within container

Tags: flutter, dart, identifier

I already checked issues with the same error message, but their solution does not seem to apply to mine. Actually I thought to implement a simple thing, now it's driving me nuts all day long. I  have a COLUMN with several CONTAINERS on one page. One of CONTAINERS contains another COLUMN which I would like to expand with a BUTTON positioned in the first cell of the COLUMN.

So I implemented this inner COLUMN with the button as the 1st CHILD and a Container as the 2nd CHILD. I have placed the if statement between "Container(" and "Child:", what didn't work, "if" after Child:" neither works... Any ideas?

```dart
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    CupertinoButton(
      child: Text('expand', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue)),
      onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
                step1Expanded = !step1Expanded;
            });
       },
    ), //Button
    Container(
       child: if (step1Expanded) step1RowWidget()
       ...
    ),
  ], //Widget
), //Column
```

On error investigation I have already learned that I must not use "if (step1Expanded) {" because curly brackets are not allowed in this code section. That is why I declared

```dart
Widget step1RowWidget()  {
   Row(
      children: <Widget>[
   ...     
}
```

Another bizarre issue: I have a global variable defined in main.dart. This works fine in the state class where I have my if statement issue (above the if statement there is a reference to the global variable). However, within the widget definition (my 2nd snippet) I receive an "Undefined name" error vor the variable.

Comment: Use ternary operator instead of if statement. `step1Expanded? step1RowWidget() : Container() `

Comment: Jesus... This cost me some hours. If you enter it as an answer, I could accept it. Any idea why the global variable is accessible only in the State class and not in the Widget definition (both in the same dart file)? @ShriHari

Comment: Yeah! I done it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could just give you an idea. 
**First Issue:**
Yes, no if's allowed. You could use ternary operator. Like this,

```
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    CupertinoButton(
      child: Text('expand', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue)),
      onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
                step1Expanded = !step1Expanded;
            });
       },
    ), //Button
    Container(
       child: step1Expanded ? step1RowWidget(): someOtherWidget()
       ...
    ),
  ], //Widget
), //Column
```

**Second Issue:** Simple Solution would be pass that variable as a parameter and then use it. Like this,

```
Container(
           child: step1Expanded ? step1RowWidget(variable): someOtherWidget()
           ...
 ),
```

```
Widget step1RowWidget(variable)  {
   Row(
      children: <Widget>[
   ...     
}
```

Hope that solves your issue!