# Expected an identifier Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, identifier

i am a beginner an i was just trying to build a button what did i do wrong

```
RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Click Me"),
        elevation: 4.0,
        splashColor: Colors.blue,
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        onPressed: ()(
          
        ),
      ),
```

i tried to understand from the main doc but didn't understand it can any one tell me in detail

[I checked q&a like this but couldn't get enough info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525720/flutter-expected-an-identifier-and-expected-to-find-when-inserting-if)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use {} for callback functions

```
RaisedButton(
    child: Text("Click Me"),
    elevation: 4.0,
    splashColor: Colors.blue,
    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
    onPressed: () {
    },
)
```

Comment: Thanks i just found that mins ago and am laughing god and i just made another problem can you help me out with that too?

Comment: Sure, happy to help